# Why does not my spring security configuration work?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

If I navigate to the url of /toQuestion using the browser, it will be opened successfully.

However, by using js code:

```
window.location.href = "/toQuestion";
```

I will be redirected back to the login page of /chief, which I have configured this way:

```
http.authorizeRequests(
                authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .mvcMatchers(
                                "/js/**",
                                "/css/**",
                                "/chief",
                                "/toQuestion").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        )
.formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/chief")
                                .permitAll()
                )
```

I have given permission of "/toQuestion" to any unauthenticated users.
Is there any additional configuration I need to set up?

Comment: "If I input the url of /toQuestion in the browser, I will redirect to the page I want successfully" what does this mean? what is the page you want? are you really redirected, or is the "/toQuestion" actually the url you want?

Comment: What I mean is that the way to input the URL can display the content 
 corresponding to the URL, but the window.location.href ="/ toquestion" of JavaScript causes redirection.

Comment: please post your raw request from the browser, and your debug log from spring security in its full, so that we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: also, you might have an issue with your javascript. Is there any additional code, or just the snippet you've shown here?

Comment: Thanks very much!After I have the advice to debug the detail of spring security, I found that the reazon is that I didn't implement the supports method of my AuthenticationProvider to indicate which authentication object it can supports.

Answer (score 0):

OK.I solved it.After I changed the level of package org.springframework.security to debug the detail,I realized that I didn't implement the supports method of AuthenticationProvider to indicate which Authentication Object this AuthenticationProvider supports.

Comment: you could add the relevant debug logs to the question so this would more be useful to someone else too